# Warhammer 40k Unit Composition - Marines

Tags: warhammer-40k

If I make my own chapter, lets just call them Flat Black, and they are all painted flat black, can I also include a hero from the Ultra Marines, painted blue, such as Magnus? Or a librarian that is painted in the blue UM colors?

Would it be legal if I followed the UM codex for my "Flat Black" chapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its perfectly fine to play your custom chapter as ultramarines. The fluff says that most chapters follow their example.

As for using special characters, yes you can use them in a non-space marine army. An FAQ in White Dwarf answered a similar question for blood angels:

Q: Can I use Commander Dante [commander of the Blood Angels chapter] as my Flesh Tearers chapter leader?
A: Yes, but keep in mind that he is the Blood Angels chapter leader, not the Flesh Tearers.

Hope that helps.